# Cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Foo' to 'Foo&' error

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

Hi Everyone i have a class Foo having a fooAddress member variable

Code in foo.h

```
Class Foo
{
String fooAddress() const;
void setFooAddress(String fooAddress)
....
String m_fooAddress;
}
```

Code in foo.cpp

```
String Foo::fooAddress() const
{
return m_fooAddress;
}

void Foo::setFooAddress(String fooAddress)
{
m_fooAddress = fooAddress;
}
```

Now i have a FooList Class which has a list of foos

Code in FooList.h

```
class FooList
{
 editFooList(Foo foo,int index);
 ...
 private:
 List<Foo> m_fooArray; 
 }
```

Now my code in FooList.cpp is

```
void FooList::editFooList(Foo foo, int index)
{
m_fooArray.at(index).setFooAddress(foo.fooAddress());
}
```

but i am getting the error 
  error: C2662: 'void Foo::setFooAddress(String)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Foo' to 'Foo &'

Since i have not defined editFooList as a const function,i am not sure why the compiler is complaining when i am trying to modify m_fooArray.Can someone please point me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your C++ reproduced in this posting accurately? Your code has `foo::` rather than `Foo::`. Also I'm seeing `QString` rather than `String` in places. Are you using Qt instead of the STL?

Comment: also "editFooList(foo foo, int index);" should not compile.

Comment: "Foo"bar springs to mind.

Comment: Yes i am using Qt ,i have corrected everything now

Comment: Did you try `editFooList(const Foo& foo,int index);`? Do you ***really*** need to pass by value there?

Comment: I passed it value because i am not modifying foo, btw i did tried `editFooList(const Foo& foo,int index);` also as you suggested but i am still getting the same error

Comment: Is `List<>` and alias for `QList<>`.  QList.at() returns a const reference.

Comment: Thanks brycem, Qlist.at() does returns a const reference,i think i know what i was doing wrong now,cannot edit a element of m_fooArray like this i suppose

Answer (score 0):

i changed my code to

```
void FooList::editFooList(Foo foo, int index)
{
m_fooArray[index].setFooAddress(foo.fooAddress());
}
```

and it is compiling now

Comment: This will copy the foo object, which doesn't seem very efficient.